# /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set version .ubantu14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, chown

when I set the EACCESS for npm and I was ran the chown command in my terminal for change owner permission but now i stuck in this 
sudo :" /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set" my version is : ubuntu14.04 LTS please help me guyz :)

Comment: Did you do what it says to do at this link:  https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions  That is the most brain-dead method of forcing an install to work I have ever seen.  `chown -R myuser /usr/local`?  Even for `/usr/local`, that is epically stupid.  And you've apparently found out why.

Comment: finally, after finding too much i am really thanked https://askubuntu.com/users/10962/user10962 at this link : https://askubuntu.com/a/471503/528411

Comment: /usr/bin/sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sudo{,2} hash -r
Refer this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419122/sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set?newreg=b2490740fb214ce79c316ad76f859e0a

Answer (score 24):

First restart your pc, and press the ESC key while Ubuntu is booting.

This will bring you up the boot menu.

Select Advanced Options.

Select your OS version in (recovery mode), and press Enter Key.

It will bring you up another screen. Now select “Drop to root shell prompt” and press Enter.

It will load a command line at the bottom of the screen.

Now run each of the following commands.

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: How to do the same on EC2 AWS?

Comment: WOrked like a charm... THANK YOU1

Comment: Worked perfectly on Mint 19.3

Comment: This worked perfectly on ubuntu 20.04
i had ran `sudo chmod -R 777 on /bin` and the solution worked

Comment: Now i m facing mysql community service could not start error after login in user Ubuntu

Comment: You are a savior!! This worked like charm!! Thanks!

Comment: You really saved my day :P

Comment: Thanks!!!! worked on vbox guest fine

Comment: Worked for me, I used below command as I was not getting the Advanced Options,  
    
 `$ init 1    
 $ mount -o remount /  
 $ chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo  
 $ chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo`  
 $ reboot    
  
as suggested by @James Risner & @justme in this thread and it worked for me. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have root user password then:

`1.Login as root user`

`2.open terminal`

`3.Enter following cmd's:-`

```
mount -o remount /
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
chown root:root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so && chmod 4755/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
chown root:root /var/* && chmod 4755 /var/*
```

If you do not have root user password then:

`1.Reboot your system in recovery mode(boot and press and hold esc button to enter in recovery mode)`

[here it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWabJ.png)

`2.Nevigate to (advance option for linux) by using down arrow button and press two times Enter`

[here it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmezh.png)

`3.Nevigate to root by using down arrow button and press Enter`

[here it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVm8f.png)

`4.Now enter following cmd's:-`

```
mount -o remount /
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
chown root:root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so && chmod 4755/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
chown root:root /var/* && chmod 4755 /var/*
```

`5.press ctrl+d and then select resume option to boot normal`

`Kudos you have made it`

Answer (score 2):

For me, I solved this by running these commands:

```
 $ init 1 
 $ mount -o remount /
 $ chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
 $ chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
 $ reboot
```

Comment: This has worked for me. I didn't have any access of root user, but after following these commands, I got it working. Thanks @James Risner and justme

Comment: best answer! fast forward

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sudo{,2} 
hash -r`

Refer this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419122/sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set?newreg=b2490740fb214ce79c316ad76f859e0a

Answer (score 1):

**Simple fix**

1-[image]

2-select recovery

3-select **root**

4-`mount -o remount,rw /`

5-`chmod u=rwxs,g=rx,o=rx /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/pkexec`

6-reboot or exit

Answer (score 0):

Its beacuase of Permission issue

```
 $ su
 Password: <type your root password>
```

Switch to root user and run the command

```
# pkexec chmod a=rx,u+ws /usr/bin/sudo
```

Then check it by typing from the user

```
$sudo -l
```

it Works fine for me

Cheers....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R
```

I've succeeded it

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you need to boot into recovery mode which provides a scroll-down menu with an option to `drop down to a root shell`.

And type these commands one after another:

```
# remount disks in read-write mode
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all

# return ownership
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo

# fix permissions
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

After that, you can reboot and log in again.

You may try this, to know if It worked:

```
sudo -l
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Alt + Ctrl + mode + F1

if login root ok if not do is

2- Alt + mode + F1

than do to path /usr/bin

3- cd /usr/bin than do is

chmod u+s sudo su mount umount sg pkexec ping passwd newuidmap newgrp newgidmap ksu gpasswd fusermount expiry chsh chfn chage unix_chkpwd

than do is

chmod g+s wall write locate unix_chkpwd

than change passwd root passwd

4- Alt + Ctrl + mode + F7

Or

5- Alt + mode + F7

than try su to login root

su

if not work do it again and change passwd user and root example my user is mizel

6- su - mizel

root only

7- su

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me**

“sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid”
Or
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set.
Reason :This error occurs when  incorrect permission or ownership is set   on /usr/bin/sudo file.

**Solution**

Step 1 : Start the server in Single user mode using  command at start.

1. *init 1*

Step 2 : Once single user mode starts use below commands

1. *mount -o remount,rw /*
2. *- chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo*
3. *- chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo*

Step 3: Now Reboot the Server and check.

1. *reboot   //(linux command line)*

[enter link description here](http://systemadmintutorial.com/how-to-resolve-error-sudo-usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0/?unapproved=247&moderation-hash=8626b45d141ca2363ceebe6b6aaf52bc#comment-247)

Answer (score 0):

This applies to those environments where they have docker / Kubernetes environment running and has host root file system mounted into the container / pod.

In this case host's root "/" is mounted as "/host" inside the pod.

kubectl exec -it mypod -- chown root:root /host/usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /host/usr/bin/sudo

I have not tried creating a fresh Kubernetes pod but I guess that should work too.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty fast forward solution to the issue:

Step 1:

```
 $ init 1
```

Step 2:

```
 $ mount -o remount /
```

Step 3:

```
 $ chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
```

Step 4:

```
 $ chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

Step 5:

```
 $ reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Login as root by running command:

```
pkexec bash
```

Then run:

```
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to hanldle this issue
I used this command to become a root user:

systemd-run --shell

after that: chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo

My problem is solved.