# /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Tags: terminal, root, sudo, chown

I have a usr/bin/sudo problem on my Mac (El Capitan).

It started when I ran into a permissions problem installing from NPM and followed their directions here: 
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

I found out that was a really stupid thing I did here:
[/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set version .ubantu14.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003748/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set-version-ubantu)

I open up my terminal and get:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff38418900: pointer being freed was not     allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug [Process was     terminated by signal 6]

This essentially kills my terminal and therefore my work.

I Command-S while rebooting to start in single user mode.  I run

```
fsck -fy
```

and my hard drive appears to be OK. I then got to:
http://osxdaily.com/2015/11/04/verify-repair-permissions-mac-os-x/ which tells me to fix the permissions as I have El Capitan and therefore cannot use Disk Utility for this.  I run:

```
sudo /usr/linexec/repair_packages --verify -standard-pkgs /
```

The terminal spits back:

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

I dig deeper:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194854/sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root/194856

```
$ type sudo
sudo is hashed (/usr/bin/sudo) 

$ ls -@@eil /usr/bin/sudo
-r-s--x--x 1 501 wheel 168448 Dec 2 2015 /usr/bin/sudo

$ md5 /usr/bin/sudo
MD5 (/usr/bin/sudo) = 7d986f7707c0f11264554cd4354ef80d
```

I then

```
$ /usr/bin/sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sudo /usr/local/bin/sudo-strange
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

I find a truly depressing answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set .   But I'm an optimist so I ignore the first answer and do what the second answer tells me to:

```
$ chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
chown: root: illegal group name
```

which tells root doesn't exist.  But when I

```
$ whoami
root
```

So I'm at a dead end and I really don't want to take two days reinstalling EVERYTHING.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the EXACT same problem as you but don't know how i got it. I had the malloc error too, and i solved that by updating to the latest version of macOS, and now the sound and terminal doesn't' work. To repair the disk permissions, try [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html). It didn't work for me but it might work for you. [How to use it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329005/mac-terminal-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-error-when-opening-termin)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you probably change permission to directoty /usr/bin. To resolve that :

Fisrt be sure that root is owner of this directory /usr/bin :

```
Chown root:root /usr/bin
```

and change permission for this directory /usr/bin/sudo:

```
chmod u+s /usr/bin/sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Permission issue

```
$ su
Password: <type your root password>
```

Switch to root user and run the command

```
# pkexec chmod a=rx,u+ws /usr/bin/sudo
```

Then check it by typing from the user

```
$sudo -l
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we mess up permission for sudo file

Enable the root user: https://www.hostmyapple.com/blog/how-to-enable-the-root-account-in-macos

Switch to root user:

```
$ su
Password: <type the root password set while enabling root user>
```

Change the permission:

```
chmod root:root /usr/local/bin/sudo
```

(if you remember the file where you changed the permission, use that file instead of usr/local/bin/sudo)

This should solve it.
If this still doesn't help, try deleting /usr/local/bin/sudo from root user.

Answer (score 0):

use `/usr/bin/sudo` to execute command

```
/usr/bin/sudo chmod 511 /usr/local/bin/sudo
/usr/bin/sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/bin/sudo

/usr/bin/sudo chown -R root:wheel /usr/local/libexec/sudo/
/usr/bin/sudo chmod -R 511 /usr/local/libexec/sudo/
```

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same issue with macOS sierra. 
After trying few other things and failing each time, I noticed that I had a pending update for my OS, installed the update and everything went back to normal.